# Test exec command of smartmontools

Tags: server, 18.04, monitoring, smart, monit

**TL;DR;** Is there any way to test `exec` command of smartd's config in similar way as it is possible to test mail command?

**In details:**
My use case is that I'm using [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor my Ubuntu Server 18.04. In my smartd.conf I tell smartmontools to:

```
/dev/sda -a -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner -M test
/dev/sdb -a -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

In `/etc/smartmontools/run.d/` I have a script called `notify-monit.sh` which, when invoked, creates a file in `/etc/monit/reports` containing smartd's report. Then in `/etc/monit/scripts` I have another bash script that is invoked by monit as a program check that returns 1 if file exists or 0 if it doesn't exist. Then monit checks the exit code and alerts if it is != 0.

This scenario is a bit complex so I would like to test it from A to Z. I run every script manually and they work fine separately but still I would feel safer to test them all in a real case scenario started by smartd.

From what I understand from smartd man page `-M test` will only try to send a test email and I see in syslog that it does exactly that. And only that. Is there any way to test whole `exec` chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this deeper I can confirm that `-M test` switch runs `exec` command.

I thought there is a problem with that but actually the test was working properly. The whole mechanism, when run by `smartd`, just wasn't working as intended and without reporting any errors. There is an issue with `run-parts`, which is used by `smartd-runner`. After some digging I approached [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509069) thread where someone posted a link to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debianutils/+bug/38022?comments=all) bug report for `run-parts` containing discussion why **it doesn't support scripts with dot in name**.

It was enough to remove ".sh" ending from `notify-monit.sh` to solve my issue. Then the test generated alert in `monit` successfully.

Tips for folks troubleshooting the same:

- You can temporarily `echo` something in `/usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner` and then check for that in `/var/log/syslog` to be sure that `smartd` invokes that script
- You can run `run-parts --list --lsbsysinit /etc/smartmontools/run.d` to be sure that `run-parts` "sees" your script(s)